# No progress installing ruby via macports. How long should this action take?

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, osx-snow-leopard, macports

I'm in the process of installing ruby using macports. I typed the following command into terminal:

```
sudo port install ruby
```

Terminal responded by returning some lines that indicated the action was working, then it just stopped returning any new lines. I typed:

```
which ruby
```

and didnt get a response, so I closed the terminal window and consequently ended the processes.

I opened a new terminal window and re-typed the original install command and now I get the following message:

```
Waiting for lock on /opt/local/var/macports/registry/.registry.lock
```

How should I proceed from here? Should I just wait? If so, how long? Will terminal try to complete this action twice? How can I know if it's working?

Comment: Thank you @ctcherry, @TinMan, and @charlie. I took your advice and installed Ruby using RVM. I'll say it was a fairly painless process. SUCESS! As an ironic aside, macports won't even let me uninstall it (more locks), so I'm just going to leave it. I hope there's no harm in that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A more appropriate thing to check, when you've seen no progress, is your system's activity.

On Mac OS, you could either open "Activity Monitor" and sort by CPU, or open a terminal and type `top -o cpu`. Watch for some app showing consistent activity, especially something with "port" in the name.

To deal with the lock... odds are REALLY good it's stale since you cut it off at the knees by closing the terminal, so use `sudo rm /opt/local/var/macports/registry/.registry.lock` to remove it and retry if you want.

I will recommend [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com) for installing new versions of Ruby. It's really convenient. Before you jump into RVM read the "Installation" and "Rubygems" pages entirely, and after installing RVM type `rvm notes` and follow the directions it spits out.

Finally, do not, under any circumstance, no matter how good an idea it seems to be, try to replace or upgrade the system version of Ruby installed by Apple. Apple installed it for their own use, and messing with it invites bad juju.

Comment: Thanks. I am decided to give macports one more try. I followed your instructions to stop the lock (twice or so) until getting a message the file no longer existed, which was the objective. I typed the original install command again and now am running into this error:    --->  Computing dependencies for ruby
--->  Dependencies to be installed: libiconv ncurses ncursesw openssl zlib readline
Waiting for lock on /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_textproc_libiconv/work/.macports.libiconv.state

Comment: should I re-apply your rm command to this file as well? Thanks for being patient with me, by the way.

Comment: I think it's safe to delete the second lock file. It's like the old saying "In for a penny, in for a pound". You'd already started the process by killing the terminal, then deleting the first lock file. Sometimes installs don't happen easily.

Answer (score 1):

"`Waiting for lock on /opt/local/var/macports/registry/.registry.lock`" means MacPorts is already running and doing things. You could check for any running "port" processes in Activity Monitor. Wait until these tasks are finished (or terminate them if you don't care that they don't finish) before trying to do other things with MacPorts.

`ps -A | grep tclsh` if you can't find the running process so you can kill it.

Answer (score 0):

A more recent way to install Ruby is via [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/). Not a direct answer to you question, but I would highly recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another vote for rvm. If you are like me, and you program on a mac, but you deploy to some other *nix, then you can make sure you have the same version of Ruby (and Rails, and gems) on each, using rvm's gemsets.

Also, you can switch among gemsets easily, so that if you find a gem that you can't get working right with Ruby 1.9.2, then you can switch to 1.8.7 or some such whilst you try to figure it out. Stuff like that.

As far as I'm concerned, you can jump right in on your mac (as yourself, not using sudo) with rvm install 1.8.7 or rvm install 1.9.2. Then make sure you switch to use the correct rvm, and make the one you want your default, and you're golden. If it doesn't work, delete it - all the gemsets will be installed below your home directory in .rvm/*

The pain you are going through now will resurface when you try to keep your system version of Mac's ruby working with all the stuff you write -- RVM is definitely easier than using Mac's Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the Tin Man mentioned, if other "lock" errors start coming up, I found disabling the internet connection for a moment was helpful to stop all port processes that were occurring.